# Editing the title & description of an Area51 proposal truncates the description

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51

When I edit the Title and Description of my [EVE Online Stack Exchange proposed site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3371/eve-online), the description text is truncated in the textbox. So instead of seeing the following in the textbox:

> Proposed Q&A site for players of CCP's Massively Multiplayer Role Playing Game.

it gets truncated to:

> players of CCP's Massively Multiplayer Role Playing Game.

This happens in Chrome 5.0.375.126 and Firefox 3.6.6 on Windows 7 64-bit.

**Update:**

If I copy and paste the full *"Proposed Q&A site for players of CCP's Massively Multiplayer Role Playing Game."* something wacky happens and it gets turned into *"Proposed Q&A site for proposed Q&A site for players of CCP's Massively Multiplayer Role Playing Game."* - note the two "Proposed Q&A site for" in the sentence.

Comment: Ok...me being a bit thick and missed a memo somewhere about the way this works, please vote to close :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text `Proposed/Beta Q&A site for` is automatically prepended to every site description. It is mandatory and thus is not included in the textbox so that it will not be removed.

This is because the description is meant to describe who the site is for, not define the scope of the site which is the basis for the Definition stage. The text is included to prevent people from mistaking it for that.

Comment: I never noticed that before. That's a bit non-obvious.